# "Refreshing" a fragment from the MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

So, there is a button in a `ListFragment`.  The  `onCLick` method of the button is implemented in the `MainActivity`(not sure if it is a proper solution, but it is what it is). When I click the button the `AlertDialog` pops up and when I choose one of the dialog options it changes the dataset my fragment is working with.

The problem is when the `AlertDialog` disappears, my `ListFragment` is still displaying old data.

Is there any way to update my `ListFragment` from the `MainActivity`?

I've tried making certain `ListFragment` methods static so that they could be called from the main activity, but those methods use non-static fields, etc. and thus cannot be static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I declared an adapter of my `ListFragment` fragment as static, as well as the I declared a list from which this adapter is being filled - as static.

From the main activity I do this:

```
ListFragment.item.add(mChosenFilePath);
ListFragment.fileList.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

where:

`item` - is a list that contains the elements that are to be displayed

`mChosenFilePath` - path of file that has been added into the `item` as a result of the dialog

`fileList` - is my adapter

Comment: still not working for me. List<MyItems> is static, MyAdapter which extends ArrayAdapter is static, but the listfragment did not refresh itself :(

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to update ListFragments by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on it's adapter (assuming that your adapter derives from `BaseAdapter` or any of it's subclasses).  The easiest way to do this would probably be set an an `DialogInterface.OnDismissListener` on your dialog.

```
myDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog){
    myBaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
});
```

You can either keep the reference to the Adapter or get it directly from the `ListFragment` depending on your implementation.

Comment: Oh, that is a shame. Seems to be such a good idea, but it dint work out. The fragment data is still not updated properly.

Comment: I got completely hammered and made it work. I will reflect on my experience in the morning xxx

Answer (score 0):

There are three possible solutions.

1. Listen for the click in your fragment instead of the Activity.
2. Set a listener on the `cancel` button of your dialog, and reload the fragment as needed.
3. Add your fragment with a tag, get it from the manager by that tag, and call the appropriate method.

Comment: so how do i actually "reload" my fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Set a tag, or id for the fragment.  You can then call a method directly on the fragment from the Activity:

```
Fragment myne = findFragmentByTag( "MyFragment" );
MyFragment target = (MyFragment) myne;
target.refresh(); // 'Refresh' method to be declared by MyFragment implementation
```

Comment: U can not cast from Fragment in this way .